# Rich text editor in Django admin - Hiding the HTML tags in the change list

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am developing a Django project where admins are able to style some content using TinyMCE. Everything works fine, except for an annoying detail.

For some model it happens that a field edited in rich text mode needs to be shown in the change list. What happens is that this field is then displayed with its HTML tags. What I would like to do is to have the equivalent of

```
{{ field|striptags }}
```

inside the change list.

Unfortunately things are not as simple as overriding an admin template, since the content already arrives at the template wrapped with the admin HTML (`<td>`). So if I simply replace

```
<tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">{% for item in result %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}</tr>
```

with

```
<tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">{% for item in result %}{{ item|striptags }}{% endfor %}</tr>
```

inside 'admin/templates/change_list_results.html' the results table appears unstyled.

> How can I have a decent preview of these fields in the change list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create an extra property on your model that returns the stripped field and use this in `list_display`.

```
class YourClass(models.Model):
    ....

    @property
    def html_stripped(self):
       from django.utils.html import strip_tags
       return strip_tags(self.html_field)
```

and in your `ModelAdmin`:

```
list_display = ['html_stripped', ...]
```

The docs for [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) mention a few other options and give you more details on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is that you don't want to see the tags, but want them to render, you may want to try this:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def some_field_html(self) :
        return mark_safe(self.some_field)
```

and then in the model admin use [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).

```
list_display = ('some_field_html')
```

"A few special cases to note about list_display:
...
If the string given is a method of the model, ModelAdmin or a callable, Django will HTML-escape the output by default. If you'd rather not escape the output of the method, use the [mark_safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47953774/8334374) function on return."